Display Freeze anytime while browsing/listening spotify
i have problem with my pc display has freeze but this pc working normally if using igpu
*nvidia driver is update
After i update this driver, my pc working normally,but the next day my pc cause same problem again.
How to fix this?
My Gpu :MSI GT1030 LP 2GDDR5

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Display freeze when using External GPU

Is this a laptop ? When does it freeze, while gaming or simply using a browser/watching a video ? It could be that your GPU is toast.

rollback your gpu driver, from device manager (right click on computer then properties)
